# Can I Build Bluetooth connectivity into a HTML5 / JS WebAPP

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a WebApp built using HTML5, JS, Jquery - but I'd now like to build some Bluetooth functionality into it in order to transfer data to another BT enabled device.

I've downloaded the Bluetooth Dev Kit and read a lot of the papers, but seems that the tools available are for Native Apps.

Can anyone advise if there are BT Group approved libraries or add ins that I could use for the purpose.

Thanks
Phil

Comment: You could build a Cordova-based app, using HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery (or Angular), with the appropriate plugins for BT communication. However this requires building and installing the application for each platform.

Comment: Thanks jcaron - we were trying to avoid the whole Native App process of App Stores etc ...

Comment: See the [Interact with Bluetooth devices on the Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web) article and the [Web Bluetooth API specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API)

Comment: It might be useful to understand what your use case is. There are alternatives to app stores (like enterprise deployment for iOS devices, for instance). Are you targeting internal users, a limited number of users, or the public at large?

Comment: Thanks for interest jcaron. It's the public at large we are targeting, but don't want the development and deployment overheads that native Apps demand.

Answer (score 1):

In practise, in 2016: **No**.

[Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-bluetooth) for the [Web Bluetooth specification](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) is practically nil.

Only Blink based browsers support it, and even then it is locked behind a user preference that defaults to *off*.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. From the tone of your answer I'm wondering if you think there may be something coming soon to do this? (When you 'in practise' - and 'in 2016' ....makes me think maybe 2017 could be different).

Comment: @CAPhil52 — Some technologies get adopted quickly, others take a very long time. I wouldn't want to make a prediction. Going from its current state to broad adoption in the space of a year is unlikely though. Keep an eye on the links in the answer for progress.

Comment: Cheers Quentin - guess I'd better sit on hands and wait...or develop something else in the meantime. Phil